# TableView Extension with Generic constraint

Tags: swift, generics

[image]Getting can not convert value of type [UITableViewCell.type] to expected argument type [_.Type].

Below is the extension

```
extension UITableView {

 func registerCells<T>(ofTypes types:[T.Type]) where T:UITableViewCell {
    types.forEach { (type) in
        let nib = UINib(nibName: type.typeName, bundle: nil)
        self.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: type.typeName)
    }
 }
}

protocol NameDescribable {
var typeName: String { get }
static var typeName: String { get }
}

extension NameDescribable {
  var typeName: String {
    return String(describing: type(of: self))
  }

 static var typeName: String {
    return String(describing: self)
 }
}

extension NSObject: NameDescribable {}
extension Array: NameDescribable {}
```

and calling statement is :

```
 mediaTable.registerCells(ofTypes: [AddCell.self,
                                       ImageMediaCell.self])
```

Comment: What `typeName` here?

Comment: type name return the name of type as String

Comment: Add the definition of `typeName` as well here.

Comment: Where have you created `typeName`?

Comment: this code works given `AddCell`  and `ImageMediaCell` exists as subclasses of `UITableViewCell`

Comment: share a demo of the problem may be in github for easy reproduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an x-y question. No generic is needed. No protocols are needed. No extensions are needed. All you need is this:

```
func registerCells(ofTypes types:[UITableViewCell.Type]) {
    for type in types {
        let typeName = String(describing:type.self)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: typeName, bundle: nil)
        self.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: typeName)
    }
}
```

That registers a table view cell subclass to an eponymous nib using an eponymous reuse identifier.

Comment: note that this doesn't answer the op's error , there must be a hidden part